# minitoc does not work correctly with \chapter*

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, minitoc

I am writing my PhD thesis using a book class, I want to have a table of contents displaying only the chapters appears in the page where the name of the part found and a mini table of contents for the current chapter appear just after the chapter name listing all sections of that chapter, I used `\minitoc` and `\parttoc` commands from the package `minitoc`, the problem is that `\parttoc`does not work and for the mini tables are shifted (chapter 1 has no mini table of content, mini table of chapter 1 appears in chapter 2 and so on)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[left=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}



%--------------------------------------------------------------

%\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc% Initialization
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables


\chapter*{Introduction générale}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction générale}\markboth{\bf \footnotesize{\emph{Introduction générale}}}{}

\part{Cerveau et modélisation de l’activité neuronale}
\parttoc


\chapter{Organisation structurelle et fonctionnelle du cerveau}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc
\section{Éléments de neuroanatomie}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Le système nerveux}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Métabolisme}
\lipsum[1]
\section{TEP}
\lipsum[1]
\section{L'Électroencéphalographie (EEG)}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Magnétoencéphalographie (MEG)}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Imagerie par résonance magnétique fonctionnelle  (IRMF)}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Modalités d'exploration fonctionnelle cérébrale}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Modélisation}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc

\section{Relations gouvernant le transport d'oxygène}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Flux sanguine}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Dynamique du volume sanguin cérébral}
\lipsum[1]
\section{désoxyhémoglobine veineuse}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Modèle de balloon}\label{balloon}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Signal BOLD}.
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Le balloon}
\lipsum[1]

\section{bold}
\lipsum[1]
\section{hemodynamic model}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Modèle Métabolique/Hémodynamique}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Estimation}
\minitoc% Creating an actual minitoc


\section{bold}
\lipsum[1]
\section{hemodynamic model}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Modèle Métabolique/Hémodynamique}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: With minitoc, you have to treat starred chapters in a special way. The documentation explains how to in detail.

Comment: @ Johannes, but I am not using starred chapters.

Comment: \chapter\*{Text}. Wenn commonly use the term star for the asterisk. You have such a starred chapter for the general introduction.